# Meaning of the phrase "A Donation Away"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Please help to figure out the meaning of the sentence. What is the function of the adverb **away** here?

> Making a difference in the lives of thousands of Albertans is only a donation away!

This was taken from [Alzheimer.ca](https://alzheimer.ca/en/ab/Get-involved/Ways-to-donate) website.

Relevant section is given below:

> **Ways to donate**
>   *Making a difference in the lives of thousands of Albertans is only a donation away!* A donation to the Alzheimer Society helps people dealing with the challenges of Alzheimer's disease and other forms of dementia.

Comment: I suppose it's a snowclone based on 'only a stone's throw away'. 'Only a step away' 'Only a roadtrip away' 'Only a Pavement away'. 'Only a heartbeat away from death'. Here, it's saying that you can become part of the Alb... (other charities are available) by making a donation. _It's easy to make a donation, and you will then be able to consider yourself included._

Comment: If you do not make a donation you are not helping. If you make a donation you are helping. So that's how far away from helping you are. One donation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: [*But the mother and child reunion **Is only a motion away***](https://www.paulsimon.com/track/mother-and-child-reunion/), long before the term "snowclone" was coined. But now everything's *just a **mouseclick** away* with online shopping even if you're in lockdown. I think it's just standard "metaphoric extension" from the more literal *easily-covered short distance to reach* to *easily-performed trivial action to achieve / obtain*.

Comment: @FF Gas (N₂, O₂ etc) was gas before the term was coined. It just wasn't called gas.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom "*X* is only a *Y* away" means that you're very close to being able to achieve result *X*, you only have to take the small step *Y* to reach it.

So they're saying that all you have to do is make a donation to make a difference in the lives of many Albertans.